# How to mark subticks at the end of a smooth curve?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,3)(2,7)
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{-1}{1.56}{t|t^2+4}%
\pscurvepoints{-1}{1.56}{t|t^2+4}{L}%
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,ticksize=-2pt 2pt,Os=1,Ds=.2]{L}{ ds }{0}{40}
\multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=1+2}{20}{\Put{6pt;(LNormal\iA)}(LTick\iA){\tiny \iB}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question: How to mark subticks at the end of a smooth path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a multiple distance of the ticks of the curve,
which is not easy to know for a curve. However:

```
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{-1}{1.53}{t|t^2+4}%
\pscurvepoints{-1}{1.53}{t|t^2+4}{L}%
```

[image]